# How to bind to '*ngSwitchCase'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to display data dynamically as I retrieve it from the server ... so I need to bind to `*ngSwitchCase`

My code

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="segments-container" padding>
      <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="thisYearString" class="segments">
        <ion-segment-button value="{{thisYearNumber}}">
          {{thisYearNumber}}
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="{{lastYearNumber}}">
          {{lastYearNumber}}
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
    </div>
    <div [ngSwitch]="thisYearString">
      <ion-card *ngSwitchCase="'2017'" class="details-segment">
        <ion-card-header>2017</ion-card-header>
        <!--Some Other Code-->
      </ion-card>
      <ion-card *ngSwitchCase="'2016'" class="details-segment">
        <ion-card-header>2016</ion-card-header>
        <!--Some Other Code-->
      </ion-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I want to to do is something like that:

`*ngSwitchCase="{{thisYearString}}"`

PS: I use String and Number since ngSwitchCase only accepts strings any ideas to overcome doing that too?

is it a good practice to add value dynamically like I did `value="{{thisYearNumber}}"`?

Comment: No thats not how you use the value attribute the angular way, use this instead ```[value]="thisYearNumber"```

Comment: Nice that worked @Abdel what about my main question?

Answer (score 2):

The structural directive already puts you in the right context to access your component variables.

If you do this:

```
*ngSwitchCase="thisYearString"
```

That will get the value from `thisYearString` defined in your component for the switch case.  Also, I've been able to switch on non-strings (it is Javascript, after all) so I'm guessing it just coerces it before it does the check.

The reason you need quotes in your example here:

`<ion-card *ngSwitchCase="'2017'" class="details-segment">`

Around the `2017` is because otherwise it would try to treat that as a variable, and would fail.